# Which boilerplate to use for reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am a reactjs beginner and looking for sample/boilerplate code projects. Is there a project that has a central component where all the api calls to the backend are handled? What is the common pattern for this?

Comment: if you can specify what you need, people will be able to help you. Have you looked into redux? Try and do some research so that you have a better idea on what is out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some boilerplate code with backend & frontend using ReactJS? the answer is MERN stack. You can get the API call working, Redux, and much more.

```
git clone https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter.git
cd mern-starter
npm install
npm start
```

More info at here http://mern.io/